# Where to create a .profile on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, path, .profile

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Which folder do I create my `.profile` file in?

I like to create a path for `/usr/local/mysql/bin` – any tips on how to export this path? I only know how to type it for `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 27):

You create `.profile` in the same folder as `.bash_profile`, namely in `/Users/your-user-name/` also available under `~` or `$HOME`.

You can add the line using a text editor or command line editor of your choice (like `vim`, `emacs` or `nano`), but you can also do it with Text Edit:

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
```

---

#### Where to put the `export` command?

One important thing: If you already have a `.bash_profile`, your `.profile` will **not** be loaded automatically. From bash's manual:

> it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and  reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

Because of that, when you already have a `~/.bash_profile` file and create a `~/.profile`, the latter will never be read by bash automatically. You can add the appropriate `export` command in your `~/.bash_profile` and it will work just fine if you always use bash:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH
```

---

#### Source `.profile` from `.bash_profile`

If you want to have a separate `.profile`, you need to manually include it from `~/.bash_profile`. Put the following in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal:

```
open .profile
```

If that doesn't work, go to your home directory:

```
sudo nano .profile
```

and add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Comment: Shouldn't need `sudo` to edit `.profile` in your home directory.

Comment: In addition it might be better to have your custom path *in front of* $PATH, so that your local MySQL binary always comes first.